# fill between in pgfplots changes legend font

Tags: pgfplots, legend, fillbetween, tikzscale

I am working on a document in which several plots are placed alongside each other. Some of them use "fill between" and some of them don't. The problem now is that depending on whether this is used or not, the legend has a different font size. Additionally, the thickness of the plots is also affected. As a work around, I now use an empty "fill between" in every plot (third tikzpicture) but this feels too much like cheating and I would love to know what is really going on here.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]
\begin{axis}[
    ticks=none, axis x line* = bottom, 
    samples= 160, domain = -3:3,    
    xmin = -3, xmax = 3,    
    ymin = 0, ymax = 3,
    legend style={at={(axis cs:2.9,2.9)},anchor=north east}]
    \addplot[name path=f, black, thick, mark=none, ] {max(2.8-2*x^2,0)};
    \addplot[name path=g, black, thick, mark=none, dashed, ] {max(1-0.3*x^2,0)};
    \addplot[name path=line, gray, no markers, line width=0pt] {0};
    \addplot[color=gray, fill opacity=0.25] fill between[of = f and line, split];
    \legend{$f$,$q$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace{5em}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]
\begin{axis}[
    ticks=none, axis x line* = bottom, 
    samples= 160, domain = -3:3,    
    xmin = -3, xmax = 3,    
    ymin = 0, ymax = 3,
    legend style={at={(axis cs:2.9,2.9)},anchor=north east}]
    \addplot[name path=f, black, thick, mark=none, ] {max(2.8-2*x^2,0)};
    \addplot[name path=g, black, thick, mark=none, dashed, ] {max(1-0.3*x^2,0)};
    \addplot[name path=line, gray, no markers, line width=0pt] {0};
    \legend{$f$,$q$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.55]
\begin{axis}[
    ticks=none, axis x line* = bottom, 
    samples= 160, domain = -3:3,    
    xmin = -3, xmax = 3,    
    ymin = 0, ymax = 3,
    legend style={at={(axis cs:2.9,2.9)},anchor=north east}]
    \addplot[name path=f, black, thick, mark=none, ] {max(2.8-2*x^2,0)};
    \addplot[name path=g, black, thick, mark=none, dashed, ] {max(1-0.3*x^2,0)};
    \addplot[name path=line, gray, no markers, line width=0pt] {0};
    \addplot[color=gray, fill opacity=0.25] fill between[of = line and line, split];
    \legend{$f$,$q$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Edit: thanks to the answer by Zarko, I now think this question is a duplicate of [Scaling problem with fillbetween in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257406/scaling-problem-with-fillbetween-in-pgfplots). For some reason, invoking fillbetween causes the scaling to suddenly affect the legend. I still haven't figured out why though.

Answer (score 3):

Cause of observed problem is scaling of TikZ pictures. If you omit, the font in legend will not not change. This lead me to thought that use of `fillbetween` library doesn't allow scaling, i.e. make scaling work as expected: it should not change font size (as far I understand how it works, maybe I'm wrong).

I made some changes in your MWE: omit scaling, introduce images width, and it works as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.45\textwidth,
    ticks=none, axis x line* = bottom,
    samples= 160, domain = -3:3,
    xmin = -3, xmax = 3,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 3,
    legend style={at={(0.97,0.99)}, anchor=north east},
                    ]
    \addplot[name path=f, black, thick, mark=none, ] {max(2.8-2*x^2,0)};
    \addplot[name path=g, black, thick, mark=none, dashed, ] {max(1-0.3*x^2,0)};
    \addplot[name path=line, gray, no markers, line width=0pt] {0};
    \addplot[color=gray, fill opacity=0.25] fill between[of = f and line, split];
    \legend{$f$,$q$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.45\textwidth,
    ticks=none, axis x line* = bottom,
    samples= 160, domain = -3:3,
    xmin = -3, xmax = 3,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 3,
    legend style={at={(0.97,0.99)}, anchor=north east},
                    ]
    \addplot[name path=f, black, thick, mark=none, ] {max(2.8-2*x^2,0)};
    \addplot[name path=g, black, thick, mark=none, dashed, ] {max(1-0.3*x^2,0)};
    \addplot[name path=line, gray, no markers, line width=0pt] {0};
    \legend{$f$,$q$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.45\textwidth,
    ticks=none, axis x line* = bottom,
    samples= 160, domain = -3:3,
    xmin = -3, xmax = 3,
    ymin = 0, ymax = 3,
    legend style={at={(0.97,0.99)}, anchor=north east},
                    ]
    \addplot[name path=f, black, thick, mark=none, ] {max(2.8-2*x^2,0)};
    \addplot[name path=g, black, thick, mark=none, dashed, ] {max(1-0.3*x^2,0)};
    \addplot[name path=line, gray, no markers, line width=0pt] {0};
    \addplot[color=gray, fill opacity=0.25] fill between[of = f and line, split];
    \legend{$f$,$q$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 because it works ... but it would be nice to know why it fails with scaling. Probably some bounding box...

Comment: @Rmano, actually I'm surprise, that scaling also affect fonts in OP MWE. And yes, I agree with you. It would be nice ... :-)