# How to use tikzscale together with pgfplots fillbetween library

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween, tikzscale

I rely on the tikzscale package to conveniently scale all my pgfplots to the right size. However, I recently ran into the problem that this doesn't seem to work with the fillbetween library. Is there a workaround for this problem, preferably still using tikzscale?

See also: [Scaling problem with fillbetween in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257406/41356)

---

MWE showing the problem:

This plot compiles fine.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,
xmax=3500,
ymin=0,
ymax=2000000000]%,

\addplot [name path=lower,color=red,dotted]
  table[row sep=crcr]{ 
200 1e7\\
1000 1e8\\
3000 1e8\\
};

\addplot [name path=upper,color=red,dotted]
  table[row sep=crcr]{ 
200 1e8\\
1000 2e8\\
3000 1e9\\
};

\addplot+[red, opacity=0.4] 
fill between[of=upper and lower];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Correct plot]

However, if I use tikzscale, put the tikzpicture-environment without any changes in the file `figure1.tikz` and use this code, strange things happen:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{figure1.tikz}

\end{document}
```

Instead of staying in the boundaries, the filled area just ignores certain points.

[image: wrong plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by installing the current version of tikz/pgf to my local texmf.